# Windbg dump analysis: what causes error 0x80004002 while asking for handle information?

Tags: windbg, dump, handle

I'm debugging the memory dump of a process, of which I assume the number of handles becoming too large. When I open the dump in `Windbg`, I see following error/warning message (I don't know if this is relevant to my question) :

```
Dir entry 8, HandleDataStream stream has too many elements (0xfefffd > 0x400000)
```

While launching the `Windbg` `!handle` extension command, I see following error message:

```
0:000> !handle
ERROR: !handle: extension exception 0x80004002.
    "Unable to read handle information"
```

I have already launched that same extension command on other memory dumps of the same process (maybe another version). Hence I don't understand the relevance of most Google results of that error code (something about a wrong interface).

Does anybody know what might cause the mentioned error code and what I can do in order to see the amount of handles in my application dump?

For your information, I'm not interested in every single handle, just the total amount of them.

**Edit after first comments**

The results of `.dumpdebug` are the following: (only handle related)

```
0:000> .dumpdebug
----- User Mini Dump Analysis

MINIDUMP_HEADER:
Version         A793 (62F0)
NumberOfStreams 13
Flags           61826
                0002 MiniDumpWithFullMemory
                0004 MiniDumpWithHandleData
                ...
Stream 8: type HandleDataStream (12), size 27D7FF98, RVA 101DEF6C
Dir entry 8, HandleDataStream stream has too many elements (0xfefffd >     0x400000)
Stream 9: type CommentStreamW (11), size 000001A0, RVA 000102E0
  '
*** "C:\Internal\Tools\Procdump\procdump.exe"  -ma  -accepteula 18732     C:\Dumps\Own_Application_PID_18732_2019_02_07_11_38_02_777_NOW.dmp
*** Manual dump'
```

(The results of .dumpdebug and Dumpchk.exe are very similar, I decided not to add them too)

**Edited after chdump.py result**

Hereby the result (partially) of chdump.py:

```
MINIDUMP_HEADER EXCLUDING SIGNATURE
version                 0xa793
internal version        0x62f0
Number of Streams       0xd
Stream Directory RVA    0x20
CheckSum                0x0
u.TimeDateStamp         2019-02-07 11:45:24
Flags                   0x61826

MINIDUMP_DIRECTORY
StreamType              DataSize                RVA
0x3                     0x754                   0x434
0x11                    0x9cc                   0xb88
0x4                     0x1588                  0x1554
0x13                    0x290                   0x2adc
0x9                     0x12250                 0x37fc9f84
0x10                    0x6b080                 0x37f5ef04
0x7                     0x38                    0xbc
0xf                     0x340                   0xf4
0xc                     0x27d7ff98              0x101def6c
0xb                     0x1a0                   0x102e0
0x0                     0x0                     0x0
0x0                     0x0                     0x0
0x0                     0x0                     0x0
_MHDesc2
Handle        TypeNameRva   ObjectNameRva Attributes    GrantedAccess HandleCount   PointerCount  ObjectInfoRva Reserved0
0x4           0x10490       0x104a8       0x10          0x3           0x7c          0x1ee0c0b     0x0           0x0
0x8           0x104c2       0x0           0x0           0x100020      0x2           0x80001       0x0           0x0
0xc           0x104d0       0x104dc       0x0           0x1           0x2           0x80001       0x0           0x0
0x10          0x1055e       0x1056a       0x0           0x20019       0x2           0x80000       0x0           0x0
0x14          0x105f6       0x0           0x0           0x1f0000      0x2           0x80002       0x0           0x0
0x18          0x1060e       0x0           0x0           0x1f0003      0x2           0x80001       0x0           0x0
0x28          0x1061e       0x1062a       0x0           0xf003f       0x2           0x7ffba       0x0           0x0
0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0
0x30          0x10652       0x0           0x0           0x1f0003      0x2           0x40002       0x0           0x0
0x34          0x10662       0x0           0x0           0x1f0003      0x2           0x40002       0x0           0x0
0x38          0x10672       0x0           0x0           0x1f0003      0x2           0x40002       0x0           0x0
0x3c          0x10682       0x0           0x0           0x1f0003      0x2           0x40002       0x0           0x0
0x40          0x10692       0x0           0x0           0x1f0003      0x2           0x40002       0x0           0x0
0x44          0x106a2       0x0           0x0           0x1f0003      0x2           0x40002       0x0           0x0
0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0
0x4c          0x106b2       0x106ca       0x10          0xf           0x44          0xfe9d9c      0x0           0x0
0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0
0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0
0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0
0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0
0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0
0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0
0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0
0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0
0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0
0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0
0x78          0x106f2       0x0           0x0           0x1f0003      0x2           0x7ffc7       0x0           0x0
0x7c          0x10702       0x1070e       0x0           0x20019       0x2           0x7fffe       0x0           0x0
0x80          0x1077a       0x0           0x0           0x100020      0x2           0x40002       0x0           0x0
0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0
0x88          0x10788       0x0           0x0           0x100003      0x2           0x40002       0x0           0x0
0x8c          0x107a0       0x0           0x0           0x100003      0x2           0x40002       0x0           0x0
0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0
0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0
0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0
0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0
0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0
0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0
0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0
0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0
0xb0          0x107b8       0x0           0x0           0x1f0003      0x2           0x40002       0x0           0x0
0xb4          0x107c8       0x0           0x0           0x1f0003      0x2           0x40002       0x0           0x0
0xb8          0x107d8       0x0           0x0           0x1f0003      0x2           0x7fddf       0x0           0x0
0xbc          0x107f0       0x0           0x0           0x1f0003      0x2           0x7fea0       0x0           0x0
0xc0          0x10808       0x0           0x0           0x1f0003      0x2           0x40002       0x0           0x0
0xc4          0x10820       0x0           0x0           0x1f0003      0x2           0x40002       0x0           0x0
0xc8          0x10838       0x0           0x0           0x1f0003      0x2           0x7fff6       0x0           0x0
0xcc          0x10850       0x0           0x0           0x1f0003      0x2           0x7fd62       0x0           0x0
0xd0          0x10868       0x0           0x0           0x1f0003      0x2           0x6f1cc       0x0           0x0
0xd4          0x10878       0x0           0x0           0x1f0003      0x2           0x40002       0x0           0x0
0xd8          0x10888       0x0           0x0           0x1f0003      0x2           0x40002       0x0           0x0
0xdc          0x108a0       0x108ac       0x0           0xf003f       0x2           0x80000       0x0           0x0
0xe0          0x108f6       0x10902       0x0           0x20019       0x2           0x80000       0x0           0x0
0xe4          0x10958       0x10964       0x0           0x20019       0x2           0x80001       0x0           0x0
0xe8          0x10a08       0x0           0x0           0x1f0003      0x2           0x40002       0x0           0x0
0xec          0x10a18       0x0           0x0           0x1f0003      0x2           0x40002       0x0           0x0
0xf0          0x10a28       0x0           0x0           0x1f0003      0x2           0x40002       0x0           0x0
0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0
0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0
0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0
0x100         0x10a38       0x0           0x0           0x1f0003      0x2           0x40002       0x0           0x0
0x104         0x10a48       0x0           0x0           0x1fffff      0x4           0xff501       0x10a5a       0x0
0x108         0x10a96       0x0           0x0           0x1f0000      0x2           0x7fff8       0x0           0x0
0x10c         0x10aae       0x0           0x0           0x1f0003      0x2           0x7fffe       0x0           0x0
0x110         0x10abe       0x0           0x0           0x1f0003      0x2           0x5ebe2       0x0           0x0
0x114         0x10adc       0x0           0x0           0xf00ff       0x2           0x73b3f       0x0           0x0
0x118         0x10b00       0x0           0x0           0x100002      0x2           0x80002       0x0           0x0
0x11c         0x10b10       0x0           0x0           0x1           0x2           0x80002       0x0           0x0
0x120         0x10b3e       0x0           0x0           0x100002      0x2           0x7d72d       0x0           0x0
0x124         0x10b4e       0x0           0x0           0x1           0x2           0x5ebe2       0x0           0x0
0x128         0x10b7c       0x0           0x0           0x1f0003      0x2           0x80000       0x0           0x0
0x12c         0x10b8c       0x0           0x0           0x1f0003      0x2           0x80000       0x0           0x0
0x130         0x10b9c       0x0           0x0           0x1f0003      0x2           0x5671f       0x0           0x0
0x134         0x10bac       0x0           0x0           0x1f0003      0x2           0x40002       0x0           0x0
0x138         0x10bbc       0x0           0x0           0x1fffff      0x4           0xbf505       0x10bce       0x0
0x13c         0x10c0a       0x0           0x0           0x1f0003      0x2           0x40002       0x0           0x0
0x140         0x10c1a       0x0           0x0           0x1f0003      0x2           0x74432       0x0           0x0
0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0
0x148         0x10c2a       0x0           0x0           0x1f0003      0x2           0x80001       0x0           0x0
0x14c         0x10c3a       0x0           0x0           0x100001      0x2           0x7feb3       0x0           0x0
0x150         0x10c48       0x0           0x0           0x1f0003      0x2           0x80001       0x0           0x0
0x154         0x10c58       0x0           0x0           0x1f0000      0x2           0x4d899       0x0           0x0
0x158         0x10c70       0x0           0x0           0x1f0003      0x2           0x7ffdc       0x0           0x0
0x15c         0x10c80       0x0           0x0           0x1f0003      0x2           0x80000       0x0           0x0
0x160         0x10c90       0x10c9c       0x0           0xf003f       0x2           0x7ffd6       0x0           0x0
0x164         0x10ce6       0x0           0x0           0x1f0003      0x2           0x80000       0x0           0x0
0x168         0x10cf6       0x10d0a       0x0           0x4           0xa3          0x28c0002     0x0           0x0
0x16c         0x10d5a       0x10d66       0x0           0xf003f       0x2           0x7ffc4       0x0           0x0
0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0
0x174         0x10db0       0x10dc0       0x10          0x100001      0x53          0x18003f      0x0           0x0
0x178         0x10e10       0x10e1c       0x0           0x20019       0x2           0x7fff4       0x0           0x0
0x17c         0x10e94       0x10ea0       0x0           0x20019       0x2           0x7fff4       0x0           0x0
0x180         0x10f1c       0x10f30       0x0           0x4           0xa3          0x28c0002     0x0           0x0
0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0           0x0
0x188         0x10f80       0x0           0x0           0x120089      0x2           0x7fffc       0x0           0x0
0x18c         0x10f8e       0x0           0x0           0xf0005       0x2           0x80001       0x0           0x0
```

It does very far: the Python script even stopped, due to a memory error, after having generated ±13 million(!) lines of results.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Verify that you have the handles information in your dump (MiniDumpWithHandleData). How did you take the dump?

Comment: The dump was, most likely, taken using `procdump -ma <PID>`, how can I be sure there is indeed handles information within the dump?

Comment: Check `.dumpdebug`. I saw a few times that task manager dumps miss this info, but if it `procdump -ma` it's should be fine.

Comment: Also check with `dumpchk.exe` If the dump file is corrupt in some way. From this message `Dir entry 8, HandleDataStream etc` it seems that your problem is not necessarily with the missing of the `HandleData` but maybe it's a corrupt dump. Can you open the dump with ClrMD of with VS?

Comment: @DudiKeleti: I've executed `.dumpdebug` and `dumpchk.exe` and edited my question accordingly.

Comment: Sorry I can't help too much. 12 (0x0C) is the [HandleDataStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/he-il/windows/desktop/api/minidumpapiset/ns-minidumpapiset-minidump_handle_data_stream) and it seems that it has an error of kind `stream has too many elements` but I don't know why. I recommend you to try to open it in VS or ClrMD or if you want, send me the dump and I try to analyze the problem by inspecting the dump data structure.

Comment: You can't (maybe it was possible if were can do it without native code), I just want to know if it can be read by VS. Although, it still not approve that handles stream is not corrupt. The error does not seem so reasonable to me. There should be no reason when you read the dump to get an error that there are too many handles in process. I looked for a bit on the web and it seems that this is a generic error that you get on all the streams types (not necessarily handles stream) when the file itself is somehow corrupted. If this is the case, then there is not much to do as far as I understand.

Comment: You can read about dump file structure, then try using your code or other libs like ClrMD or dnSpy, read the file yourself and then try to read and handles the stream. Chances are it will not help you solve the problem and you will find that you failed reading but maybe it will help somehow to understand exactly where it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Format of Minidump file is almost Documented You can parse the file yourself   without having to Rely on windbg
say with python

the Error seems to be Explicit there is some corruption in the `_MINIDUMP_DIRECTORY->DataSize`

The Max Number of Handles iirc is limited to 10000 handles per process
(browse for Raymond Chens blog old new thing)
so there is must be some hardcoded limit for the stream size  which when violated
results in that error

below is a quickly churned python script that takes a dump and dumps the raw data 
open the dump in hexeditor and peer around or maybe patch to recover part handle information

```
%%writefile chkdump.py
import sys
import os
import struct
import datetime
scriptname = os.path.split(sys.argv[0])[1]
if (len(sys.argv) != 2 ):
        sys.exit("usage python %s path_to_dump" % scriptname)
fin = open(sys.argv[1],'rb')
if( fin.read(4) != 'MDMP' ):
        fin.close()
        sys.exit("not a windbg dump file no  MDMP signature")
print ( "MINIDUMP_HEADER EXCLUDING SIGNATURE") 
dmphdr = struct.unpack("<HHiiiiQ",fin.read(28))
print ( "%-20s\t0x%x") % ( "version", dmphdr[0] )
print ( "%-20s\t0x%x") % ( "internal version", dmphdr[1] )
print ( "%-20s\t0x%x") % ( "Number of Streams", dmphdr[2] )
print ( "%-20s\t0x%x") % ( "Stream Directory RVA", dmphdr[3] )
print ( "%-20s\t0x%x") % ( "CheckSum", dmphdr[4] )
print ( "%-20s\t")     % ( "u.TimeDateStamp" ),
print ( datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(dmphdr[5]))
print ( "%-20s\t0x%x") % ( "Flags", dmphdr[6] )
print ("\nMINIDUMP_DIRECTORY ")
print ("%-24s%-24s%-24s") % ("StreamType" , "DataSize","RVA")
streamdata = []
for i in range(0,dmphdr[2],1):
    streamdata.insert(i,struct.unpack("<iii",fin.read(12)))
    print ("%-24s%-24s%-24s") % ( hex(streamdata[i][0]),
                    hex(streamdata[i][1]),hex(streamdata[i][2]))    
HStreamLoc, = [z for (x,y,z) in streamdata if x == 0xc]
HStreamDSize, = [y for (x,y,z) in streamdata if x == 0xc]
fin.seek(HStreamLoc)
sizeof_HDStream = 16 
HDStream = struct.unpack("<iiii",fin.read(sizeof_HDStream))
assert (HDStream[1] * HDStream[2] + sizeof_HDStream ) == HStreamDSize
print ("_MHDesc2")
sizeof_MHDesc2 = 40
HDesc = []
print ("%-14s%-14s%-14s%-14s%-14s%-14s%-14s%-14s%-14s") % ("Handle" ,"TypeNameRva",
    "ObjectNameRva","Attributes","GrantedAccess","HandleCount","PointerCount",
                                                "ObjectInfoRva","Reserved0")
for i in range(0,HDStream[2],1):
    HDesc.insert(i,struct.unpack("<Qiiiiiiii",fin.read(sizeof_MHDesc2)))
    print ("%-14s%-14s%-14s%-14s%-14s%-14s%-14s%-14s%-14s") % ( hex(HDesc[i][0]), 
    hex(HDesc[i][1]), hex(HDesc[i][2]), hex(HDesc[i][3]),hex(HDesc[i][4]),
    hex(HDesc[i][5]), hex(HDesc[i][6]),hex(HDesc[i][7]), hex(HDesc[i][8]))
```

when executed it would return data like this for handle stream

```
MINIDUMP_HEADER EXCLUDING SIGNATURE
version                 0xa793
internal version        0x61b1
Number of Streams       0xd
Stream Directory RVA    0x20
CheckSum                0x0
u.TimeDateStamp         2019-02-14 02:38:24
Flags                   0x61826

MINIDUMP_DIRECTORY 
StreamType              DataSize                RVA                     
0x3                     0x94                    0x1dc                   
0x11                    0xcc                    0x270                   
0x4                     0xc40                   0x33c                   
0x13                    0x388                   0xf7c                   
0x9                     0x1100                  0x91f0                  
0x10                    0x4f30                  0x42c0                  
0x7                     0x38                    0xbc                    
0xf                     0xe8                    0xf4                    
0xc                     0xb28                   0x3798                  
0xb                     0x58                    0x294c                  
0x0                     0x0                     0x0                     
0x0                     0x0                     0x0                     
0x0                     0x0                     0x0                     
_MHDesc2
Handle        TypeNameRva   ObjectNameRva Attributes    GrantedAccess HandleCount   PointerCount  ObjectInfoRva Reserved0     
0x4           0x29b4        0x29cc        0x10          0x3           0x2d          0x54          0x0           0x0           
0x8           0x29e6        0x0           0x0           0x100020      0x2           0x3           0x0           0x0           
0xc           0x29f4        0x0           0x0           0x100020      0x2           0x3           0x0           0x0           
0x10          0x2a02        0x0           0x0           0x100020      0x2           0x3           0x0           0x0           
0x14          0x2a10        0x0           0x0           0x1f0000      0x2           0x5           0x0           0x0
```

EDIT

i have edited the code to print handle , type name , object name 
and put it [here](https://github.com/blabberer/pydmpchk)

the results will be like

```
Handle  TypeName        ObjectName
0x4     Directory       \KnownDlls
0x8     File            No ObjName
0xc     File            No ObjName
0x10    File            No ObjName
0x14    ALPC Port       No ObjName
0x18    Key             \REGISTRY\MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Nls\Sorting\Versions
```

it should print all the 16.7 million handles in your dump if they exist

Comment: Pardon my lack of knowledge, but (as mentioned in my second) edit I've run the Python script you provided. I've added the first lines of the result to the original question, but the script stopped prematurely due to a `MemoryError` after having generated ±13 million of lines. Can you confirm this indeed an indication that I'm dealing with such high amount of handles that a handles leak is a probable cause for my issue?

Comment: since the assert was validated in my code it may seem that number of handles in your dump is  ( 0x27d7ff98 - 0x10 ) / 0x28  
ans = 0x00FEFFFD which is the same number of handles .dumpdebug also confirms  that is a lot of handles  improve the python script to print handle details and parse the text :) possibly a laborious task

Comment: i updated the script to print the handle along with type name and object name commented out the previous outputs and dumped it in github

Comment: you are welcome.  so did you find which handle is leaking ? why not update your original question with followups to close the circle ?